# "initiating a variable" in Javascript: what does it mean?

Tags: javascript

I am learning now JS but get so often this concept of "initiating a variable". Could anyone give me a good answer? Cheers

Comment: You mean _initializing_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declaring a variable with var makes it local to the function it's in. Otherwise it could be available in other functions which can be confusing if you use the same variable name in other functions without declaring them with var...

Answer (score 3):

`var name = 'john';` is declaring a variable and assigning the value 'john' to it, aka initializing it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply means giving it a value so it's ready to use.

It's the next step from simply "declaring a variable" which you'll see in languages such as C, C#, Java, etc., which is more "making a variable ready to use, but leaving it 'empty' for now".

Comment: You still (should) declare variables in js - `var new_variable;`